# Prevent network structure exposure when training on other people's GPUs

Tags: linux

I need to train on someone else's GPU because they don't want to provide the data。
Is there any way to make it less easy for them to get my source code ?

Comment: git, SVN, Dropbox, nfs, sftp - there are tons of ways to resolve this. Most of them are off-topic here

Comment: As for your source code: Look into obfuscators for the programming language you use. Besides that, get a contract in place that forbids the other party from reusing or reverse engineering your code.